# Performance of two left joins versus union

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, left-join, union

I have searched but have not found a definitive answer. Which of these is better for performance in SQL Server:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM dbo.Table1 T
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.Table1ID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T.ID = T3.Table1ID
WHERE T2.Table1ID IS NOT NULL
    OR T3.Table1ID IS NOT NULL
```

or...

```
SELECT T.*
FROM dbo.Table1 T
    JOIN Table2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.Table1ID
UNION
SELECT T.*
FROM dbo.Table1 T
    JOIN Table3 T3 ON T.ID = T3.Table1ID
```

I have tried running both but it's hard to tell for sure. I'd appreciate an explanation of why one is faster than the other, or if it depends on the situation.

Comment: Look at the execution plan.

Comment: If you can't get a good answer here, you might want to try at the DBA Stack Exchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: please do include other info like `Execution plan` or indexes defined..

Comment: Why are you using a left join in this setup?  to me, it looks like you should be using an inner join.

Comment: @Limey - Left join was used because inner join would return rows that exist in BOTH t2 and t3, whereas I needed either one but not necessarily both. Gordon's answer was perfect here. Thanks!

Comment: @mayabelle:  now, I noticed the OR, kinda just glanced over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two queries do not do the same things.  In particular, the first will return duplicate rows if values are duplicated in either table.

If you are looking for rows in `Table1` that are in either of the other two tables, I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from Table2 t2 where t2.Table1Id = t1.id) or
      exists (select 1 from Table3 t3 where t3.Table1Id = t1.id);
```

And, create indexes on `Table1Id` in both `Table2` and `Table3`.

Which of your original queries is faster depends a lot on the data.  The second has an extra step to remove duplicates (`union` verses `union all`).  On the other hand, the first might end up creating many duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! Originally I was going to return some values from t2 and t3, which is why I was debating between left `join` vs. `union`, but later it turned out I didn't need them and forgot that I should then use `exists`. Good point also, on the duplicates. I noticed that after I posted the question and was planning to use `distinct` but of course that worsens the performance also. Thanks!