# Choosing between values using left join or union

Tags: sql

I have a table **A** with columns **ABK** and **ACK**. Each row can have a value in either **ABK** or **ACK** but not in both at the same time
**ABK** and **ACK** are keys to be used to fetch more detailed information from tables **B** and **C**, respectively
**B** has columns named **BK** (key) and **B1** and **C** has columns named **CK** (key) and **C1**
When fetching information from **B** and **C**, I want to select between **B1** and **C1** depending on which column in A (**ABK** or **ACK**) is ***NOT*** null
What would be better considering readability and performance:

1

```
select COALESCE(B.B1, C.C1) as X from A 
left join B on A.ABK = B.BK
left join C on A.ACK = C.CK
```

OR

2

```
select B.B1 as X from A join B on A.ABK = B.BK
UNION
select C.C1 as X from A join C on A.ACK = C.CK
```

In other words should I do a left join with all the tables I want to use or do union?
I am guessing that readability wise the UNION is better, but I am not sure about performance

Also B and C do not overlap, i.e. there is no duplicates between B and C

I don't think the answer in the question pointed as a duplicate of mine is correct for my case since it focus on the fact that there could be duplicates among tables B and C, but as stated B and C are mutually exclusive

Comment: The end result is completely different.  If you want to link the 3 tables, you `JOIN`.  If you want to combine the 3 tables into 1 big table, you `UNION`.    Google the difference between the 2.

Comment: Hey Eric, how the results will be different? Keep in mind that my end result is determined by the select clauses. I think both will return the same values. If you can provide an example or explanation on how they will be different it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of two left joins versus union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829425/performance-of-two-left-joins-versus-union)

Answer (score 0):

your two queries aren't necessarily accomplishing the same thing.

Using LEFT JOIN will create duplicate rows in the result if there are duplicate values in either table, whereas UNION (as opposed to UNION ALL) automatically limits to remove duplicate values if applicable. Therefore, before thinking about performance, I would decide which method to use based on whether you are interested in preserving duplicates in your results.

See here for more info: [Performance of two left joins versus union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829425/performance-of-two-left-joins-versus-union).

Comment: You are right. In my case I know B and C have no duplicates between them. I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Shouldn't we mark this as a duplicate of the question you made reference?

Comment: Yes I think so, it seems to be a duplicate :)

Comment: Hey Ron, I did not consider it as duplicate since the answers in the post you mentioned are focusing too much on the duplicate rows case.
As I stated in the question B and C are mutually exclusive, i.e. there are no duplicates among them

Answer (score 0):

First, you can test the performance on your database and your data.  You can also look at the execution plans.

Second, the queries are not equivalent, because the `union` removes duplicates.

That said, I would go for the first version using `left join` for both readability and performance.  Readability is obviously a matter of taste.  I think having all the logic in the `select` makes it more apparent what the query is doing.

More importantly, the first will start with table `A` and be able to use indexes for the additional lookups.  There is no additional phase for removing duplicates.  My guess is that two joins is faster than two joins *and* duplicate removal.